# Difference in create table properties in hive while using ORC serde

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Below is the structure of one of the existing hive table.

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename`(
col1 datatype,
col2 datatype,
col3 datatype)
partitioned by (col3 datatype)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'field.delim'='T',
  'serialization.format'='T')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'maprfs:/file/location'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='{\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}',
  'numFiles'='0',
  'numRows'='0',
  'rawDataSize'='0',
  'totalSize'='0',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1536752440')
```

Now i want to create a table with same properties, how do i define below properties in create table syntax.

> field delimiter and seralization format
>   TBLPROPERTIES to store numFiles, numRows, radDataSize, totalSize (and what all  other information we can store in TBLPROPERTIES option)

Below is one of the create table syntax which i have used

```
 create table test_orc_load (a int, b int) partitioned by (c int) stored as ORC;
```

Table properties which i got using show create table option.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_orc_load`(
  `a` int,
  `b` int)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `c` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse/alb_supply_chain.db/test_orc_load'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1537774167')
```

Comment: which hive version are you using? could you run `analyze` statement and see what's the output after that, or just run `show tbleproperties`

Comment: Hive version --> Hive 2.1.1-mapr-1710,  Below is the output for `show tableproperties tableName`                                                                       
show tblproperties test_orc_load;
OK
transient_lastDdlTime   1537774167
Time taken: 0.53 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)